# Existence of Fisher Information

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

When we define Fisher information as the variance of the score function $ \frac{\partial \log f(X|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$, are we assuming the regularity conditions?

Obviously we need the regularity conditions to prove that $\mathbb{E}[ \frac{\partial \log f(X|\theta)}{\partial \theta}] = 0$ and 
$I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}[- \frac{\partial^2 \log f(X|\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}] $ as well, but what about the actual definition itself?

In that case, can we say that the Fisher information of uniform distribution $\mathit{U}(0,\theta)$ is 
$I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}[(\frac{\partial \log f(X|\theta)}{\partial \theta})^2] = \frac{n}{\theta^2}$.

Comment: We are assuming the regularity conditions.

Comment: So, the Fisher information of uniform distribution does not exist?

Comment: Not defined is what I say.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3087453/321264) answer.