# Cramer rao low bound of uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, estimation

I was given a task to show empirically that the scattering holds up Cramer rao low bound.

At first I had to calculate the estimator $ T' = E(2X_1\mid \max X_i)$

which is equal to $=\frac{n+1}{n} \max X_i$

Then I was need to run a sample in R with some parameters.

Here is my code:

```
theta = 5
n = 1000
error1 = c()
error2 = c()

for (i in 1:15){
  U = runif(n, min=0, max = 5)
  T_1 = 2*U[1]
  T_2 = ((n+1)/n)*max(U)
  error1 = c(error1, (T_1-theta)^2)
  error2 = c(error2, (T_2-theta)^2)
  
}
```

Ok, now for Cramer rao low bound I have to calculate $\frac{1}{I(\theta)}$

but there is no Fisher information for $U\sim[0,\theta]$

So, how can I show **empirically** (in R) that Cramer rao low bound hold here?

Comment: Note the way I set $$ U\sim[0,\theta] $$ entirely in MathJax.

Comment: Not sure what the question is asking for, but Cramér-Rao bound is not applicable here because of the same reason Fisher information is not defined here in the usual sense. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3087453/321264.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) is the variance of the score. The [score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)), in turn, is the gradient of the [log-likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Log-likelihood) with respect to the parameter vector.

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \text{Var}\{s(\theta)\} = \mathbb{E}[(s(\theta) - \mathbb{E}[s(\theta)])^2]$$

The score is defined as $s(\theta) = \frac{\partial \log \mathcal{L}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the likelihood function.

The expected value of the score at the true parameter is $0$, so the Fisher information becomes:

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \mathbb{E}[s(\theta)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial}{(\partial \theta} \log f(X; \theta))^2 | \theta]$$

Let's now find the Fisher information of your estimator for the uniform distribution.

The probability distribution function (pdf) of the uniform distribution is:

$$f(x; \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}$$

The likelihood function is then $\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}$, so the log-likelihood function is $\log \mathcal{L}(\theta) = - \log (\theta)$.

Let us now express the score by taking the derivative of the log-likelihood function.

$$s(\theta) = -\frac{1}{\theta}$$

Finally, let us compute the Fisher information of the *uniformly distributed random variable* (not the estimator's Fisher information!).

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \int_0^{\theta} \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot (-\frac{1}{\theta})^2 dx = \frac{1}{\theta^3} \cdot \theta = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$$

Now that we have the Fisher information of the uniformly distributed random variable, the [Cramér-Rao lower bound (CRB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) is equal to $\theta^2$.

All that is left to do is to compute the variance of the estimator. To do so, you just take the empirical variance. Now, you can see how close your estimator comes to the CRB.

Comment: Cramér-Rao bound is not applicable in the first place because a key 'regularity condition' is violated here, namely the fact that the support of the distribution depends on the parameter of interest.

Comment: So there is no way to calculate empirically the Cramer-Rao bound?

Comment: Hey David Cian, you sure that you answer is correct?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot delete my answer, I've flagged it some time ago but still no response from mods. If someone else can help delete it, please do. @Amitn no, my answer is not correct, Nch's answer is

Answer (score 1):

Cramer - Rao lower bound does not hold for Uniform distribution not only due to the absence of regularity. The estimator $\frac{n+1}{n}\max X_i$ has the variance
$$ \text{Var}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\max X_i\right) = \dfrac{\theta^2}{n(n+2)} 
$$
which does not bounded from below by $\frac{\text{const}}{n}$.

Comment: And what about the $T=2X_1$ estimator?

Comment: What do you mean? Cramer - Rao inequality stated that for regular distributions, the inequality holds for any unbiased estimate. Is we have at least one estimate s.t. inequality fails, then the conditions of theorem does not fulfilled. After that it is meaningless to check this inequality further for any other estimate: regularity is absent, Fisher information is absent too.

Comment: very strange. Because the lecturer explicitly asked us to show empirically that scattering sustains Cramer - Rao inequality